# Get count of ConcurrentBag items within ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a Concurrent Dictionary:

```
public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentBag<string>> pendingReq = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentBag<string>>();
```

How can i return the count of items in a concurrent bag?  What ive tried:

```
pendingReq.Where(x => x.Key == imei).Select(x => x.Value.Select(x => x.Any())).Count() > 0
```

Comment: `pendingReq.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == imei).Value?.Count ?? 0`?

Comment: Actually you would be better with `TryGetValue` i am guessing any linq method on a concurrent dictionary is going to be a huge performance hit

Comment: `pendingReq.TryGetValue(imei,var our value) ? value.Count : 0`

Comment: Thanks alot perfect!

Comment: Also note, as soon as you do something like this, you lose thread safety, you are likely better to just use a normal dictionary with a lock, unless you want optimization for lock free reads you have benchmarked it, and you dont care if your count is stale

Comment: Pattern matching to handle possible nulls in your dictionary: `var result = pendingReq.TryGetValue(imei, out var bag) && bag is { Count: var c } ? c : 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Linq on dictionaries, you lose out on what makes a dictionary great, the constant lookup time. Why have a potential O(n) when you can have an O(1)?

```cs
if (pendingReq.TryGetValue(imei, out var bag))
{
    // use bag.Count
}
```